# Android - WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and writing app's log

Tags: android, logging, android-permissions

All I want is to be able to write a log/exception report for my app inside a very specific folder (related to my app) in order to understand failures and exceptions, so this is the code I'm using:

```
File logFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/appname/log.txt");
if (!logFile.exists()) {
    try {
        if (logFile.getParentFile().mkdir()) {
            if (!logFile.createNewFile())
                showPopup(context.getString(R.string.app_name), "error creating log file");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
try {
    BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true));
    buf.append(text);
    buf.newLine();
    buf.flush();
    buf.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For the above to work, I have to add the following permissions:  android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE but when the user reads it, it says both reading and writing the external storage and understandably, this is scaring away the user. Is there a better way to log my app's behavior and use a less scary permission for that?

Comment: is writing storage really that scary..?

Comment: @Raptor42, apparently it is :) I'm developing a small app that receives notifications for a friend of mine and I had to add this logging. Several users asked him why the app reads/writes from/to their storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, switch from:

```
File logFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/appname/log.txt");
```

to:

```
File logFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(), "log.txt");
```

Not only does this avoid manual string concatenation when creating your path, and not only does this stop cluttering up the user's external storage with random app-specific directories, but it now means that you can have:

```
<uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
  android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

to eliminate `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` on API Level 19+.

Beyond that, try raising your `targetSdkVersion` to 4 or higher. Quoting [the docs for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE):

> Note: If both your minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion values are set to 3 or lower, the system implicitly grants your app this permission. If you don't need this permission, be sure your targetSdkVersion is 4 or higher.

Comment: Thank for a detailed response. What will be the resulted path of this context.getExternalFilesDir() ? The targetSdk is 22 (min is 15) so this is not an issue.

Comment: I wonder why writing permission gives me a reading permission as well (I only need to write, not read). If it was only writing without reading, maybe it would lower the worrying of users, at least psychologically :)

Comment: @Amos: "What will be the resulted path of this context.getExternalFilesDir() ?" -- inside of whatever base directory external storage is in for the current user, it will be in `Android/data/your.application.id.goes.here/`, if I remember the path correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "your folder name");
storageDir.mkdir();
```

Put this code to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```